# Why is all my code highlighted in red?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

All my code looks like this in every file in the entire solution. It doesn't happen in other projects, just this one. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have probably set the on option for the "Highlight Code Coverage". You can go to the `Code Coverage Results` window and click the `Code Coverage Coloring` to turn it off.

Check out the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like that feature doesn't exist in VS Community 2013.